# Losing first hundred pings

Tags: ping, packet-loss

My internet connection seemed slow, so I did:

```
sudo ping -f www.google.com
```

The strange thing is that I see I'm losing the first couple hundreds of pings, but after that it behaves as it should behave. Any idea why this might be happening? Hardware issue or ISP issue?

Comment: Next time run `traceroute www.google.com` and repost - this will give you an idea, on where the connection fails.

Comment: I just did this. It printed "* * *" for the 30 hops. Changed it to 90 hops with the same result. Does this mean something?

Comment: This indicates, that already the first step from your PC to the rest of the world is broken. Assuming you have a wireless router, this might indicate trouble with the WLAN.

Comment: But I could still have internet connection then?

Comment: You could, technically. All this seems to indicate is a high level of packet loss, which may result in a seemingly slower or less responsive connection.